# generating a random number

Tags: python, random, discord.py

I am trying to build up discord bot through pip discord.py. After command !random I want to ask user for any number and bot will then generate random number between 0 and entered number. It doesn't rly work for me and because i don't know much things about discord.py, I ask there :)

code:

```
import random
elif message.content.startswith("!random"):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Enter a number: ")
    num = await client.wait_for_message(int)
    numm = int(num)
    randomnum = random.randint(0, numm)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, randomnum)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: File "c:/Users/Adam/Desktop/discord/discord_bot.py", line 84, in     on_message
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'type'

Comment: whats line 84 say?

Comment: The code shown here works (I'm going to assume you have an opening if statement). Your error mentions line 84, so you'll have to show us that line. Most likely you are trying to add a class to a float, instead of adding the result of a method call on that class to the float

Comment: Please read this: [mcve].

Comment: yea sorry for later answer. line 84 is: num = await client.wait_for_message(int) --- and you assume right, there are other elif-s before it --- and also - i am testing the bot on mine discord server not in command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import random
elif message.content.startswith("!random"):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Enter a number: ")
    def check(msg):
        return msg.content
    reaction.content = await client.wait_for_message(author=message.author, check=check)
    numm = int(reaction)
    randomnum = random.randint(0, numm)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, randomnum)
```

You should also check if the reaction is a int

(added squaswin's reaction. note that the code is not tested)

Comment: it says error: line 87, in on_message
    num = int(reaction)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Message'

Comment: This does not return what you think it does. The check you give to `wait_for_message` should return a boolean of whether the message recieved is valid for purpose. The actual return value of the `wait_for_message` function itself is still a message, therefore you will need to use `reaction.content`

Comment: @squaswin Yea you are right, in my own bot I do this as well.